# Show cmd window when calling a bat file with popen

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

I have this code that calls a bat file with popen:

```
jobname = A2
fname = routineUEL

 def issue_command(*args):
      import subprocess
      process = subprocess.popen(args, stdout=subprocess.pipe, stderr = subprocess.pipe, shell = true)

  args = [['c:\users\desktop\\rel.bat', jobname, fname, '8', '1', ' c:\abaqus_jobs']]

  for arg in args:
       out, err = issue_command(*arg)
```

The bat file is:

```
  @echo off
  call ifortvars.bat intel64
  cd %5
  abaqus job=#1 user=%2 cpus=%3 gpus=%4 interactive
```

The thing is: when I run the python script the bat commands run in the background, no cmd window opens. When I manually run the bat file the cmd window opens. I'd like the cmd window to open also with python. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If want the command window to appear then you can execute it via the `cmd.exe`.

`cmd.exe /K 'c:\\users\\desktop\\rel.bat'`.

`/K` is instructing the `cmd.exe` to execute the batch file and remain open.

Comment: I have another question: In the python script I call an auxiliary bat file containing the line you suggest, but I'd like to still be able to transfer the arguments to rel.bat. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

@jpcgandre in said auxiliary bat file, is only that one line of code contained in it? Or is there more than that? And are you wanting to append that line to rel.bat? Can you be more specific? here is one solution:

```
with open("rel.bat","a") as text_file:
    print("cmd.exe /K 'c:\\users\\desktop\\rel.bat'", file=text_file)
```